# why is Data.Sequence.reverse O(n)?

Tags: haskell

The docs say `Data.Sequence.reverse` is O(n).  Couldn't a finite sequence type be "reversed" by setting a flag? (Effectively, which end to "start counting" from.)

Comment: It could, but then you'd have to expand the structure to carry that flag around. Evidently the maintainers of Data.Sequence decided that wasn't worth it.

Comment: I'd write a such a custom flag-carrying `Seq` variant, if I needed it.

Comment: For most use-cases one wouldn't be happy about the performance overhead that the management of an extra flag would introduce. Let `Seq` be what it is. What you need is a simple wrapper over it, which will abstract over the flag as well. We have two clearly separable abstractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just one flag, you will have problems. Suppose I want

```
xs <> reverse xs
```

How could I calculate that? With just one flag, I'd have to perform an expensive reverse before appending. To actually do this *right*, you need more flags, spread around the tree. *All* around the tree. Every node in the tree needs to carry reversal information. This is definitely possible, but it's somewhat expensive. Even worse, every step of every operation has to manage the reversal flags appropriately, which is a bit of a nightmare for whoever has to write and maintain the code. This idea has been worked out in a paper somewhere (I don't remember which one) but it's no fun in practice.

If you have an algorithm that relies essentially on reversing, then you should use a custom sequence type with lots of flags, and include just the operations you need (if you're basing your type on `Data.Sequence`, you should probably steal one bit from each size field). But I don't think such algorithms are terrifically common.

Comment: Did you mean `><`?  If so, I'm not sure why the need to incur the expense of reversing upon concatenation is an objection to a single flag.  This just delays the expense until it is actually needed, I would think?

Comment: @Alan, `<>` is (depending on base library version) either a function of type `(<>) :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a` or a method of the `Semigroup` class with a similar signature. It's much more widely known than `><` in the general Haskell community, and for sequences `(<>) = (><)`. Delaying the expense until it's needed can be good, but can also make performance hard to predict and in many cases bad. In fact, I've been working on making a number of sequence operations do their work *more* eagerly to combat this, and have managed to improve benchmark performance quite a lot..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it could.

However, this adds a small price to every lookup (one must first check the flag!), and the payoff only comes to users that use `reverse` a lot. This latter group was probably judged to be small. Since throwing the appropriate flag onto the type can be done client-side, it makes sense *not* to pay this price in the library for every use of every function. Instead, the programmer that intends to call `reverse` a lot is forced to make this performance tradeoff choice if they want it, which seems perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: "one must first check the flag!" not for each element (only once per function call), only `><` operation require reconstruct the whole structure

Answer (score 1):

Well you could define

```
data S a = S { forward :: Seq a , backward :: Seq a }
```

and then implement all operations with the invariant that

```
forall a :: Type, s :: S a  : reverse (forward s) == backward s .
```

This doubles the cost of each, but gives constant-time `reverse`.